# How can I Filter Serilog logs to different sinks depending on context source

Tags: serilog

I am trying to log to specific serilog sinks depending on the context source, I am not able to get it working by adding filters to the sinks. Both sinks are logging the data from both sources.

```json
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=XXXXX",
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false,
    "EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule": false
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.File",
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "O:\\logs\\Test.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{EventId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 20000000,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true
        },
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByExcluding",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'NAMESPACE_A')"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        },
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByExcluding",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'NAMESPACE_B')"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
  }
}
```

If I add a filter to the root it will filter (exclude) the logs from Namespace_B ok but this is not what I want. The filtering by sink does not appear to work.

I have tried several suggestions but cannot get it working, any help appreciated.

```json
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=XXXX",
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false,
    "EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule": false
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.File",
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByExcluding",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'NameSpace_B')"
        }
      }
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "O:\\logs\\MOBILEflowAPI\\MOBILEflowAPI.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{EventId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 20000000,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        },
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Namespace_B')"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
  }
}
```